# Rare exception "android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: ServiceDisabled" - what does this means?

Tags: android, google-authentication, accountmanager

**EDIT 3 (Jully)**

Problem is now back again!

```
android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: ServiceDisabled
```

So my email app is not able to connect to GMail anymore.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

**EDIT 2 (March 7)**

Maybe the creation of an "ID clients OAuth 2.0" for Android is solving this issue..
This ID has to be created on this page
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Investigation ongoing..

---

**EDIT**

I think this is related to this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/be-careful-everybody-who-is-using-oauth-2-0-to-access-gmail-google-gsuite-apis/

How should I do to have my app approved to use the [oauth2:https://mail.google.com/   scope](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)?

---

<s>**Feedback of affected user - is it the cause of this?**</s>

He created many Google account (to do some tests).
Could this be related to a too big amount of Google accounts created, accounts that are 'linked' to his initial email address (using the same initial account for recovery)? *Wrong assumption*

---

My email app is using AccountManager to access GMail (with OAuthToken ) and it's working fine (since 2102), except that I now have a peculiar exception that happens **only with a specific Google account**

This seems to be a quite new behavior

Here is the error is:

```
W/System.err: android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: ServiceDisabled
W/System.err:     at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:2507)
W/System.err:     at android.accounts.AccountManager.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:2350)
W/System.err:     at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

**Questions:**

1. What **exactly** does the "android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: **ServiceDisabled**" error means?
2. Why on earth is this only happening with this google account? (and probably for some other ones, but this seems really rare as per users feedback). Should I check some Android Google account Settings for this accounts..? Which ones?

So, same code goes well for about 10 accounts I tested on my Phone, and it fails with this very specific Google account! Why?

FYI, I opened an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127454208

**Note:**

According to the owner of this account, the app was working before, and suddenly stopped working: I am in the process of investigating when it happens and if he can give me some hints about some possible actions he took at that time.

Thanks beforehand for your help.

---

**Some info I gathered:**

I managed to debug this a bit and found that the stacktrace go further in cpp:

```
jboolean res = env->CallBooleanMethod(mObject, gBinderOffsets.mExecTransact,
        code, (int32_t)&data, (int32_t)reply, flags);
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f76a50c/core/jni/android_util_Binder.cpp

I found out that "res = onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);" (i.e. android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69) from AIDL)  is called with

```
code = 2 (probably android.accounts.AccountManager.VISIBILITY_USER_MANAGED_VISIBLE = 2)
data : a Parcel Object 
reply : another Parcel Object 
flags = 17
```

Which seems fine, and works for all other Google accounts!

I also found out that the error code in [AccountManager.convertErrorToException](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/98199ae/core/java/android/accounts/AccountManager.java#2194)
 was code [ERROR_CODE_INVALID_RESPONSE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/98199ae/core/java/android/accounts/AccountManager.java#157)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem understood and solved!

Since January 2019, [some OAuth2 scopes are restricted](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes).
Also, the [Additional Requirements for Specific API Scopes](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy#additional-requirements-for-specific-api-scopes) page sates:

> Enforcement of the requirements in this section will begin on January
>   15, 2019 when all new applications must undergo a new application
>   review process before accessing certain API scopes. Applications
>   submitted for verification before January 15, 2019 will be given a
>   grace period to come into compliance, and must submit for re-review no
>   later than February 15, 2019. To learn more about these new
>   requirements, read our blog post, Elevating user trust in our API
>   ecosystem, and the OAuth Application Verification FAQ.

In order to have your Android apps being compliant with this, you must create a new "ID clients OAuth 2.0" for Android.

This ID has to be created on this page https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

The odd thing is that all this seems related to G Suite and Google APIs, not Android SDK.
It's probably because the OAuth part of the Android SDK uses the Google API behind the scene, more precisely, the [AccountManager#getAuthToken](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/accounts/AccountManager#getAuthToken(android.accounts.Account,+kotlin.String,+android.os.Bundle,+android.app.Activity,+android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback,+android.os.Handler)) method does use it.

Comment: Hi, an id client oauth for android was created automatically but it didn't work, i deleted it created a new one but still.. Do you think it might a question of time ? Like it needs some time to be active ? If not do you have an idea ? i receive the same "android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: ServiceDisabled" Thank you

Comment: Hi, I think it depends on the OAuth scope you are using. I suggest you to read carefully this page https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes 
;-)