# How to create Credential for my Android Apps

Tags: android, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am a junior Android developer and don't know how to solve this problem. I used YouTube Data API for getting YouTube comments. I found sample code for Java and paste to my project, but some methods weren't found. I added code example for credentials. Can you help me? `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp` and `LocalServerReceiver` weren't found:

```
 public Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(Integer.parseInt(CLIENT_SECRETS));
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    return credential;
}
```

### Update

I rewrite a code example and don't get any result:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText link = findViewById(R.id.editTextLink);
        textResult = findViewById(R.id.textResult);
        Button sonuc = findViewById(R.id.buttonSonucGetir);
        sonuc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (link.getText().toString().length() != 0) {
                    String link_string = link.getText().toString();
                    videoId = parseVideoName(link_string);
                    getResultsFromApi();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lütfen Link giriniz !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
        });
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
    }
 public static String parseVideoName(String s) {
        String[] find;
        if(s.contains("youtu.be/")) {
            find = s.split(".be/");
            Log.d(TAG, "parseTableName: " + find[1]);
        }
        else{
            find = s.split("v=");
            Log.d(TAG, "parseTableName: " + find[1]);
        }
        return find[1];
    }

    private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube mService;

        MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new YouTube.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
        }

        private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            List<String> channelInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

            YouTube.CommentThreads.List result = mService.commentThreads()
                    .list("snippet");
            try {
                CommentThreadListResponse response = result.setKey(DEVELOPER_KEY).setVideoId(videoId).execute();
                List<CommentThread> channels = response.getItems();
                Log.d(TAG, "channels: " + channels);
                if (channels != null) {
                    CommentThread channel = channels.get(0);
                    channelInfo.add("Text original is '" + channel.getSnippet().getTopLevelComment().getSnippet().getTextOriginal() + ", " +
                            "and author display name is " + channel.getSnippet().getTopLevelComment().getSnippet().getAuthorDisplayName());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "channelinfo: " + channelInfo);
                Log.d(TAG, "response: " + response);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG,"response error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return channelInfo;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                return getDataFromApi();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
            if (strings == null || strings.size() == 0) {
                textResult.setText("No results returned.");
            } else {
                strings.add(0, "Data retrieved using the YouTube Data API:");
                textResult.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", strings));
            }
        }
    }

    private void getResultsFromApi() {
   
        if (!isDeviceOnline()) {
            textResult.setText("No network connection available.");
        } else {
            new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
        }
    }
 private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
    private void chooseAccount() {
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
                this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
            String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
            if (accountName != null) {
                mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                getResultsFromApi();
            } else {
                // Start a dialog from which the user can choose an account
                startActivityForResult(
                        mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                        REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            }
        } else {
            // Request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission via a user dialog
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts).",
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                    Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    textResult.setText(
                            "This app requires Google Play Services. Please install " +
                                    "Google Play Services on your device and relaunch this app.");
                } else {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                        data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName =
                            data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        SharedPreferences settings =
                                getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.apply();
                        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        getResultsFromApi();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(
                requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    private void acquireGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        }
    }

    void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
            final int connectionStatusCode) {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        Dialog dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
                MainActivity.this,
                connectionStatusCode,
                REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Exception:

```
2020-12-14 22:36:57.821 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
2020-12-14 22:36:57.821 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:83)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.821 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:68)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.821 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source:1)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.821 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source:55)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.821 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:269)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.821 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:294)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.821 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.822 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.822 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.822 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.822 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.mmb.rafflegram.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.getDataFromApi(MainActivity.java:135)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.822 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.mmb.rafflegram.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:156)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.822 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at com.mmb.rafflegram.MainActivity$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:117)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.822 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.822 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.822 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.823 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.823 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-12-14 22:36:57.823 6387-6442/com.mmb.rafflegram W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: I'd recommend to go carefully through the steps specified by the official [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/android) document. Then, if things still won't work, come back and update (that is: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65264575/edit)) your question above.

Comment: Don't just copy paste when you start learning stuff, understand what the code does, identify if a specific block suits your needs, if not then remove it.

Comment: @stvar I solved problems but not i got an deadlock error. What can i do? when execute CommentThreadListResponse on background Async Task

Comment: Does the Quickstart's demo program function for you?

Comment: @stvar yes. I solved deadlock but now doesn't get any response from `CommentThreadListResponse`. I  got response from `YouTube.CommentThreads.List result = mService.commentThreads()
                    .list("snippet");`
After this, I call `CommentThreadListResponse` but not get any response

Comment: So your have `YouTube.CommentThreads.List result = mService.commentThreads()                     .list("snippet").setVideoId(...); CommentThreadListResponse response = result.execute(); List<CommentThread> comments = response.getItems();` and then `comments.isEmpty()` gets you `true` *and all these without any exception thrown*?

Comment: @stvar `YouTube.CommentThreads.List result = mService.commentThreads()
                    .list("snippet").setVideoId(videoId);

            Log.d(TAG, "result: " + result);

            CommentThreadListResponse response = result.execute();
            Log.d(TAG, "response: " + response);`

LOGS: 

`D/MainActivity: result: {part=snippet, videoId=lhFU5H5KPFE}`
and nothing for response ? no response coming

Comment: But you did not answer to the second part of my question: were there any exceptions thrown? Please edit your question above, posting a complete code context to see what's that about.

Comment: ok @stvar but now i dont get an exception. I need a result but not result anymore.

Comment: If your log does not contain a line like `response: ...`, then the statement `Log.d(TAG, "response: " + response);` was not executed. *That means that an exception got thrown during `result.execute()`!* (I assume here that your log has a line of form `result: ...`.) You have to find what kind of exception was that. It may well be that the API returned an error that was mapped to an exception by the client library you're using.

Comment: @stvar `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null` an exception occured. How can i resolved?

Comment: What method throws this exception?

Comment: this method : `CommentThreadListResponse response = result.setKey(DEVELOPER_KEY).setVideoId(videoId).execute();`

Comment: Are the variables `DEVELOPER_KEY` and `videoId` set properly?

Comment: @stvar exactly. Developer_key is a API key. Videoid is true. I don't understood what is a problem.  Could the error be related to the credential ?

Comment: `videoId` is supposed to be a string, not a boolean value.

Comment: @stvar `public static String parseTableName(String s)` getting String

Comment: Please post an entire stack trace (add that to your question above as update #2).

Comment: @stvar I updated. Thank you so much. I made you tired..

Comment: Sorry, I did not made myself clear: I needed to see the the entire *exception* stack trace.

Comment: @stvar sorry. I updated

Comment: Did you proceed as in the section [Step 4: Prepare the project](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/android#step_4_prepare_the_project) by having a proper `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file as exemplified there? That XML file needs the line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />`.

Comment: @stvar `com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException` and `Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: ServiceDisabled`

Comment: Looking at your source code above, I saw that your deviated from the Quickstart sample code: your `getResultsFromApi` doesn't inquire about Google Play Services; neither chooses an account. Why is that so?

Comment: @stvar no, it gave Main Activity Class. 
 ```mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it: you said *no,  it gave Main Activity Class*. Please rephrase or add details. Please also answer to my previous question: *Looking at your source code... Why is that so?*

Comment: @stvar I fully updated code

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55118077/8327971) help you?

Comment: @stvar Nope :( What can i do ?

Comment: @stvar Do you know something about extra? How can i solve ?

Comment: I'd recommend *to start afresh executing with max. precision, in the given order, each and every step of the Quickstart demo* (do not modify its code). Then, if that worked, adapt it to your needs (listing comments).